# How do I access variables in execution script from executed script

Tags: powershell

I have a running PS1-script (start-webserver.ps1) running as a "web server" that is listening for http calls that executes a script (example: script2.ps1) executed in the call to the "web server".
I am executing the script with Start-Job. How can I in the executed script (script2.ps1) access variables in start-webserver.ps1?

## Start-WebServer.ps1

```
$allObjects = @()
foreach ($item in $items) {
    $objectUID = $item.Attributes.Value                          
    $propertiesHash = [ordered]@{UID = $objectUID}                           
    $properties = $items.ChildNodes
    foreach ($property in $properties.ChildNodes) {
        $propertyName = $property.Attributes.Value                               
        $propertyValue = $property.innerText                                 
        $propertiesHash.Add($propertyName, $propertyValue)
    }
    $object = New-Object PSObject -Property $propertiesHash                          
    $allObjects += $object
}
$job = Start-Job -Name "$identifier" -FilePath "Path\To\ScriptToExecute.ps1" -InputObject $allObjects -ArgumentList $propertiesHash
```

## ScriptToExecute.ps1

```
'Script executed!' | Out-File -Path ".\output.txt" -Encoding UTF8 -Append
$propertiesHash | Get-Member | Out-File -Path ".\output.txt" -Encoding UTF8 -Append
$allObjects | Get-Member | Out-File -Path ".\output.txt" -Encoding UTF8 -Append
```

I end up with an "output.txt" with the following content:
Script executed!
*Empty line*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define in ScriptToExecute that you are receiving params

By default it is set in the $args variable.

In your case, simply using $args[0] will be sufficient.

i.e.:

```
'Script executed!' | Out-File -Path ".\output.txt" -Encoding UTF8 -Append
$args[0] | Get-Member | Out-File -Path ".\output.txt" -Encoding UTF8 -Append
```

If you want to also receive $allObjects, you need to modify Start-WebServer to this:

```
$job = Start-Job -Name "$identifier" -FilePath "Path\To\ScriptToExecute.ps1" -InputObject $allObjects -ArgumentList @($propertiesHash,$allObjects)
```

then do this:

```
'Script executed!' | Out-File -Path ".\output.txt" -Encoding UTF8 -Append
$args[0] | Get-Member | Out-File -Path ".\output.txt" -Encoding UTF8 -Append
$args[1] | Get-Member | Out-File -Path ".\output.txt" -Encoding UTF8 -Append
```

Nicer way of doing this is to specify the param in ScriptToExecute

i.e.:

```
param($propertiesHash, $allObjects)
'Script executed!' | Out-File -Path ".\output.txt" -Encoding UTF8 -Append
$propertiesHash | Get-Member | Out-File -Path ".\output.txt" -Encoding UTF8 -Append
$allObjects | Get-Member | Out-File -Path ".\output.txt" -Encoding UTF8 -Append
```